# Permutations of a string using a stack in Java

Tags: java, string, permutation, string-concatenation

I am having a problem figuring out why my code wont work. The code is supposed to push a string onto a stack. then it will put a "+" sign in front of the string. (example  [+dog]. Next, it pops the stack. It moves the Characters on the right side of the "+" sign to the left side in the string, one by one(ex. [d+og] [o+dg] [g+do] and push these onto the stack.
this repeats over and over until all the permutations of the string end with a plus sign(example  [dog+][dgo+][god+][gdo+][odg+][ogd+] it then sees if the string on the stack has a "+" sign at the end, and if it does it prints the statement out.
Here is my code:

The problem i'm having is in my last else statement. I cant get the characters to move to the other side of the "+" sign.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class string_Perm{

    public static void main(String[] args) {// this takes user input for a string and runs it through the program
        Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
        userInput = inputString.next();
        // test print statement below
        //System.out.println(userInput);
        PermString(userInput);

    }
    public static void PermString(String userInput){
        Stack permStack = new Stack();
        permStack.push("+" + userInput);//this pushes the user input string onto the stack.                 
        // test print statement below
        //System.out.println(permStack);
        while(!permStack.isEmpty()){
            String currentItem = (permStack.pop().toString());// it then pops the top of the stack while the stack isn't empty.
            if(currentItem.endsWith("+")){
                currentItem.substring(0,currentItem.length()-1);// if the string ends with a +, you print the string without the + at the end
                System.out.println(currentItem);

            }
            else{// this else statement is where i am having trouble its supposed to split the string at the plus sign and then move each char one by one to infront of the "+" sign, then push it onto the stack.
                String[] charArray = currentItem.split("\\+");
                System.out.println(charArray[charArray.length-1]);
                for(int i = 0;i <= charArray.length; i++){
                    String getWord = charArray[charArray.length - 1];
                    String addWord = (charArray[i] + "+" + getWord.substring(0,i) + getWord.substring(i,0));
                    System.out.println(addWord);
                    permStack.push(addWord);

                }



            }



        }





    }



}
```

Any changes to this code or different methods are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give the current output of the program, if you give it an example string (e.g. "dog")?  Sometimes seeing the output helps us "zero in" on the problem much better than looking at code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with your indexes. My suggestions:

1. The for loop needs to iterate over the length of the second string in `charArray` (charArray holds the string not the characters!).
2. You can use a Stringbuilder to remove the character at position i instead of doing your two `getWord.substring()`.

Here is what I suggest for the code in the for loop:

```
String[] charArray = currentItem.split("\\+");
for(int i = 0; i < charArray[1].length(); i++){
   String getWord = charArray[charArray.length - 1];
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getWord);
   String addWord = (getWord.charAt(i) + charArray[0] + "+" + sb.deleteCharAt(i).toString());
   System.out.println(addWord);
   permStack.push(addWord);

}
```

Try this and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you this worked. 
I changed some of my print statements to make the outcome just print the strings.